# How to downgrade python version in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, python, python3, version

I need to change my python version from 3.8 to 3.6 ?
How can I achieve this in Ubuntu 20.04. I tried pyenv, but when I try to use pyenv like `pyenv global 3.6.0` then I do `python3` and I have still 3.8 verision.

Comment: Do you really need to change the python version or do you just need to be able to run certain scripts with a different version?

Comment: I Need to run script with a differen version

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify that because changing the global python is a very bad idea and really not a good solution if you only need this for certain scripts. Are you just looking for `/usr/bin/python3.6 /path/to/script.py`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do not downgrade the system version: it's likely that some parts of the system would stop working. Never change `/usr/bin/python3`, and avoid putting an older version of `python3` before it in the `$PATH`.

The [deadsnakes archive](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) provides packages of most supported Python versions for currently supported Ubuntu LTS versions. To make these packages available, follow the usual instructions to enable a PPA. Then install the package(s) you want.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

You can then create a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) for your chosen Python version and with a chosen set of packages.

```
python3.6 -m venv ~/python/foo-3.6
sh -c '.export PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1;  ~/python/foo-3.6/bin/activate; pip install …'
```

To run a program in this environment, source the `bin/activate` script in a shell.

```
$ bash
$ export PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1
$ . ~/python/foo-3.6/bin/activate
$ ./my_python_program
```

Comment: When setting up the venv, it reports and error with ensurepip something non-zero exit status. The package python3.9 installed from deadsnakes doesn't include pip. How do I solve that?

Comment: @PuiHoLam Ask a new question about your problem and copy-paste the full output.

Answer (score 10):

**Alternatively, you can create a virtual environment.**

Suppose you have python **3.8 (or higher)** installed on the system, but for a specific task, you need **python 3.7 (or lower)**. The best idea is (not to downgrade) to Create a virtual environment with python 3.7(or any 3.x, **change the commands below according to your desired version. Below is an implementation of a virtual environment with python 3.7**)

Steps: (Checked August 2022)

1. Install python 3.7 and it’s virtual environment packages.

   `sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev python3.7-venv`

**NB**: If you'll get errors like:
`E: Couldn’t find any package by glob ‘python3.7’` , stating that the packages can not be installed.

run the following commands below, then re-run the install command above:

`apt update`

`sudo apt install software-properties-common`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`

2. Find out where your python 3.7 is located by this command:

   `which python3.7` (Should be something like **/usr/bin/python3.7**, if not found, then install python 3.7 manually)
3. Create Virtual Environment in the Home directory.

   `cd`

   `mkdir virtual_env`

   `/usr/bin/python3.7 -m venv ~/virtual_env/venv_with_python3.7`

   `source ~/virtual_env/venv_with_python3.7/bin/activate`
4. `python --version` (Should be python 3.7 now)
5. Done. Python 3.7 can be used in this virtual environment. Type `which python`, you’ll see you have created python 3.7 in a virtual environment, rather than in the system globally.

   Run `deactivate` when you need to deactivate.